# Displaying data from related records in a flat table after selecting a feature on the map

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service

I have an ESRI feature service with 2 Layers: 
layer 0: Administrative boundary (0) and 
layer 1: Tables: MEP_global_data.DBO.mep_catalog (1)

Layer 0 has the geometry of the administrative boundaries of the world. 
Layer 1 is a flat table with no geometry

The 2 layers are linked by a country code column in each.

I've done lots of searching but can't find any examples or a way to do the following:

When I click on a country displayed on a world map (layer 0) via leaflet in my browser, I want a popup that displays data from the flat table (layer 1) for that country.

Is there an example that does something similar I can review or can someone suggest a way I can make this happen?

Layer: Administrative boundary (0) and Tables: MEP_global_data.DBO.mep_catalog (1)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not permanently joining your table to the layer of admnistrative boundaries ?

Comment: The relationship between layer 0 and layer 1 is 1 to many.  Long term, as data is added to the table, I don't think joining or merging the two will be practical.

Answer (score 1):

A bit belated, but at version 3.10 the ArcGIS API for JavaScript added internal logic which simplifies displaying information from a related table in a popup.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/popup_relatedrecords.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_popuptemplate.html

Comment: i also wrote an esri leaflet plugin to assist with the same: https://github.com/jgravois/esri-leaflet-related